# Dictionary of dictionaries with constant keys in python

Tags: python

So I have a list of objects like this:

```
['bob', 'tob', 'mom'], ['tom', 'apa'], ['cat']
```

and I'd like to create a dictionary of dictionaries like this:

```
{
    {0: 'bob', 1: 'tob', 2: 'mom'},
    {0: 'tom', 1: 'apa'},
    {0: 'cat'}
}
```

What's the pythonic way to get this done? Thanks!

Comment: That's not a legal dictionary of dictionaries: there are no keys (for example, what is the key for `{0:'bob',1:'tob',2:'mom'}`?)

Comment: Keys are made of numbers as it shows in the target. what do you mean?

Comment: The key for `bob` is a number. What is the key for `{0:'bob',1:'tob',2:'mom'}` (that is, the *outer* dictionary)?

Comment: For the outer collection, what you've written is a `set`, not a `dict`—there aren't keys and values, just values. However, even _that_ isn't legal, because you can only put hashable things into a `set`, and `dict`s are not hashable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want to convert a `list` of `list`s into a `set` of `dict`s where the index is mapped to the value.

Well, you can't do that, because a `set` can't hold unhashable values like `dict`s. But you can convert it into a `list` of those `dicts` easily.

Each `list` can be converted into a `dict` just by `dict(enumerate(l))`. This gives you a list that can be used in exactly the same way as the original `list` (so `d[0]` returns the same thing as `l[0]`), which seems like what you want.

To put them together into a list, just use a list comprehension.

```
>>> l=[['bob','tob','mom'],['tom','apa'],['cat']]
>>> d=[dict(enumerate(i)) for i in l]
>>> d
[{0: 'bob', 1: 'tob', 2: 'mom'}, {0: 'tom', 1: 'apa'}, {0: 'cat'}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You understood my poorly worded question and gave me a perfect answer. Good teacher!

Answer (score 0):

```
index_as_key = dict(enumerate(['bob','tob','mom']))
```

If you just want the index of list item while you iterate over the list, no need to create an intermediate dict:

```
for i, item in enumerate(['bob','tob','mom']):
    # do something
```